# PHP GD library returns broken image

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, xampp, gd

My problem is that I can not create images using php library in Codeigniter.

For example, I am using the sample code in php.net below:

```
 header("Content-Type: image/png");
 $im = @imagecreate(110, 20) or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
 $background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
 $text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
 imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  "A Simple Text String", $text_color);
 imagepng($im);
 imagedestroy($im);
```

This code gives me a broken image. I researched on gd options by using gd_info() which are like:

```
[GD Version] => bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
[FreeType Support] => 1
[FreeType Linkage] => with freetype
[T1Lib Support] => 
[GIF Read Support] => 1
[GIF Create Support] => 1
[JPEG Support] => 1
[PNG Support] => 1
[WBMP Support] => 1
[XPM Support] => 
[XBM Support] => 1
[JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support] =>
```

I am using it in Codeigniter on latest version of XAMPP local server. What is wrong with the code or local server?

Comment: I just tested your code and it is working fine. which version of xampp are using? Plus, have you enabled php_gd2 library on php.ini ?

Comment: yes it is enabled. xampp version is 3.1.0